# Is it possible to host a .NET Core site on a hosting service like Arvixe?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, .net-core

Arvixe says they don't officially support .NET core on their Personal Class Pro web servers but their tech support did not even realize that they supported .NET at all so I am not too confident in the opinion.

I am on one of the newer "Plesk" servers which will run .NET 4.6.1 and have been with them for a while.

Is it possible to deploy a "Self-Contained" version of Asp.net Core from Visual Studio? This should have all the files needed to run the site but did not work. Is there a way to make this work or do these type of hosting sites actively discourage the practice because of the overhead?

Comment: My hoster supports it. https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/app-service/

Comment: I don't know why the downvotes. Pretty much standard for SO these days, it seems.I removed the last two questions about hosting sites, hoping that people can focus on the main question. I can't get it to work and looking for an answer.

Comment: Nooo.... No.... Don't use them anymore. They have bad support now. You better find other alternatives here, https://windowswebhostingreview.com/arvixe-asp-net-hosting-alternatives/

Comment: lol, thanks for the advice...

Comment: Followup. I did indeed leave Arvixe to go to another hosting service that better supported .net CORE. Sorry, @David-Browne-Microsoft but it wasn't Azure. I have been working with Azure at work though...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The hoster is probably using IIS, and while the bits needed to host .NET Framework ASP.NET sites are part of Windows, the bits needed to host .NET Core on IIS are not.

See: [Host ASP.NET Core on Windows with IIS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=aspnetcore2x)

In particular, in addition to .NET Core, this requires installing the "[ASP.NET Core Module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/aspnet-core-module?view=aspnetcore-2.1)," which "creates the reverse proxy between IIS and the Kestrel server."

Comment: I had thought that the Self-Contained deployment version contained kestral  and was now self-contained but when I could not get it working I wanted to confirm that was so.  Thanks for clearing that up.